# Building PCI Compliant applications using node.js

Tags: node.js, payment-gateway, pci-compliance

We want to build an application using node.js, which we want to integrate with a payment gateway.

My though is, we will develop another application which will be PCI compliant.
So my main application doesn't need to be PCI compliant.

What are the different possible ways through which this can be achieved in node.js applications.

I found one node module - balanced.js which takes care of this issue.

https://docs.balancedpayments.com/1.1/guides/balanced-js/

Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Balanced is just another tokenization solution which provides node.js integration. You'll find Stripe, BrainTree and BlueSnap do the same. They even offer hosted checkout pages to nearly rid you of the PCI compliance.

Please note that this is not a coding question so you might get flagged here :)